# Scaping all items of a dependent dropdown menu

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, drop-down-menu

I am new in python but I am trying since two days to get the information of a dependent dropdown menu. All tutorials or instructions I saw are just limited on a one-dimensional dropdown (dd). I am happy I would just get the items of the first dropdown.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
page = get("https://www.autodoc.de/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
options = soup.find("select",{"name":"model_id"}).findAll("optgroup")
```

But I think this is the wrong procedure.

Many thanks!

In best case I would have a dataframe or .csv with all possible items.
Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN99V.png)

(the numbers of the items represent the indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Watch the network traffic via the network tab in the brower's Inspector (available via right-click); when you choose something for the first time, there's a request to `car_selector.json`, there's also one on page load which contains the initial data you're looking for.

(Alternatively, you might want to pilot a browser via Selenium or similar)